# Integer makes Array return wrong value

Tags: excel, vba, integer

I defined the following Array:

```
Global Locations_Array() As String
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Locations").Activate
TotalRowsLocations = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ReDim Locations_Array(1 To TotalRowsLocations, 1 To 6) As String
```

According to this I expect the first row of the array to be row 1.
I used this array to name new worksheets in my workbook, and that started at 1, and ended where it should.

However now I call again on this array with the following code:

```
Sub Get_Lat_Lng()
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim data_row As Integer

    Call Fill_Array_Locations

    totalrowsdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Locations").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

    TotalRowsDataLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Locations_Array(row, 1)).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For row = 2 To totalrowsdata
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Locations_Array(row, 1)).Activate
        If (UCase(Locations_Array(row, 5))) = (UCase(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet(row, 7))) And (UCase(Locations_Array(row, 6))) = (UCase(Worksheet.ActiveSheet(row, 8))) Then

            For data_row = 1 To TotalRowsDataLookup
                If (UCase(Locations_Array(row, 2)) = UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Locations_Array(data_row, 1)).Cells(data_row, 5))) Then
                   Cells(data_row, 7) = Locations_Array(row, 5)
                   Cells(data_row, 8) = Locations_Array(row, 6)
                   Exit For
                End If
            Next data_row

            Exit For
       End If
    Next row
End Sub
```

And it returns an "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"
When I check for the values in this line of code row has the value of 0 due to being an Integer. Is there a way to make this Integer start at 1 instead of 0? I found the option to set :

```
Option Base 1
```

But this interferes with the rest of my code.

Comment: Where do you define the value of `row`?

Comment: I extended the code snippet in OP to show that

Comment: There is not an index `0` element of array but you use `row` as index when its value is equal to 0. `Locations_Array(row, 1)`. You shouls assign `row` 1 or whatever is needed befor you use it as index.

Comment: Yes that is what I found out. But is there a way to make the Integer Row start at 1 instead of 0

Comment: `Row = 1`. `Option Base 1` has no effect on the initialisation of the numeric variables. They are equal to 0 by default in vba. `option base` determines first index  of arrays whether they are equal to 0 or 1. Also, you have determined first indexes of  your array is equal to 1.

Comment: I am afraid that would interfere with me looping through the rows further down in my code.

Comment: I extended the code snippet in my OP further, to include the entire subroutine.

Comment: Perhaps I can move  " TotalRowsDataLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Locations_Array(row, 1)).UsedRange.Rows.Count " to within the first FOR statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining an integer for `Dim row As Integer` withough assigning a value to it will default to `row = 0`.  If you want a different value then you must assign the value you want to it before you use it.

Try:

```
Dim row As Integer
row = 1
```

Provided yo uhave data in each row of your `Location_Array` up to `totalrowsdata` then your `For Loop` will redefine `row = 2` as the starting value and increment up to `totalrowsdata`.

The best way to understand the effect the change will have on your code is to try it and see.  If it doesn't work as you think, try using F8 to step through each line and check the value of `row` with each loop.

Comment: I extended the code snippet in my OP further, to include the entire subroutine. I better posted it all at once, sorry for that. I don't see how this will go with using Next row within my loop. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Get_Lat_Lng()
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim data_row As Integer

    Call Fill_Array_Locations

    totalrowsdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Locations").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

    Row = 1 'Row should be at least 1

    '"Row" should be at least 1 before here.
    TotalRowsDataLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Locations_Array(row, 1)).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For row = 2 To totalrowsdata
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Locations_Array(row, 1)).Activate
        If (UCase(Locations_Array(row, 5))) = (UCase(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet(row, 7))) And (UCase(Locations_Array(row, 6))) = (UCase(Worksheet.ActiveSheet(row, 8))) Then

            For data_row = 1 To TotalRowsDataLookup
                If (UCase(Locations_Array(row, 2)) = UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Locations_Array(data_row, 1)).Cells(data_row, 5))) Then
                   Cells(data_row, 7) = Locations_Array(row, 5)
                   Cells(data_row, 8) = Locations_Array(row, 6)
                   Exit For
                End If
            Next data_row

            Exit For
       End If
    Next row
End Sub
```